# Why base class constructor isnt called first

Tags: c#, .net, clr

When using easy syntax to initialize derived class fields by directly assigning values to them, compiler emits an IL code which first initializes derived class fields and then call base .ctor. Why it doesnt call base .ctor fields and initialize the derived class fields. What if I would have fields which depend on base class's fields?

I would love to put some code sample here but I am posting this question from my mobile phone.

Comment: Fields can't depend upon base class fields, or even it's own fields, because fields cannot reference `this` in their initializers.

Comment: @Anthony, yes, but I think that's simply part of the OP's question.  Why are we tortured and not allowed to use `this` in field initializers?  (unlike, say, Java)  I assume in both cases it provides a stronger guarantee of safe code.  But sometimes it makes me sad.

Comment: For your answer, consider reading [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because it needs to handle the case where a virtual method or intializer is called within the constructor.

Comment: It seems `virtual` methods can be the reason here. Since if they are overridden they might need to reach derived class fields as these methods might be called from within base class's methods.

Answer (score 2):

Eric Lippert has a two part series on his blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one.aspx

Just mentioning here for your convineance. Hope this helps.

```
Calling methods on derived types from constructors is dirty pool, but it is not illegal.
```

And stuffing not-quite-constructed objects into global state is risky, but not illegal.